# PostgreSQL asking for a GROUP BY although it seems I don't need it

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I checked the documentation and I don't understand why I'm asked for a `GROUP BY`.
Here is my request:

```
SELECT n.title, n.date,
jsonb_agg(
  jsonb_build_object('type', fb.type, 'name', fb.name, 'id', fb.id)
) as illus
FROM news n
LEFT JOIN files fb
  ON fb.id = (n.illustration ->> 'val')::integer
where n.id = '38'
```

PostgreSQL asks me to put `n.title` and `n.date` in a GROUP BY clause, but I don't understand: I will only have one result as I have my `WHERE` clause.
When I add `GROUP BY n.title, n.date` I have my result, but I should have it without this line, no?
If I read the documentation (and other similar questions on stackoverflow), GROUP BY is when you have several possible results and you want to... group them :)

Comment: _You_ might know it's only a single row, but Postgres can't know that. The join might produce multiple rows even if `id` is the primary key (btw: do not compare numbers with strings)

Comment: You are using an aggregate function, `jsonb_agg`. That means the rules as shown here [Group by](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) apply.

Comment: I thought PostGreSQL engine could assume that when you have a unique "`WHERE`" you expect only one result. Because actually my request is more complicated than that and I have to repeat all I have after the "`SELECT`" in the"`GROUP BY`" and I think it's a waste of lines...

Comment: What does a unique `where` means?

Comment: I thought it was understandable: it's when the "`WHERE`" clause designates only one row in the table.

Comment: In theory Post**g**reSQL _could_ know that all rows will contain the same `name` but the parser simply doesn't check that. The feature you are probably referring to is with regards to unique/primary key columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an aggregate function (`jsonb_agg`) and "normal columns" (`title` and `date` of table `news`) in your `SELECT` clause.

For an aggregate function, PostgreSQL takes all rows of a group, puts them into this function and gives you only one result back, namely the output of the function.
PostgreSQL will see your result as one big group, if you do not tell it what it should `GROUP BY` for making (possibly) more and therefore smaller groups.

For all the other non-aggregate colums of your result set, PostgreSQL is now in need to also give only one result per group, as the result of your query will only have one row per group (becaues this is how the aggregate function works). PostgreSQL will not pick one of the values occuring in the group at random, this would be inconsistent and without any meaning. 
Instead it ensures that all the values it could pick, are exactly the same, meaning that all the values of one output column are the same inside one group. Therefore this value has some meaning to this group and is used in the result.

What you try to argue here is, that your query returns only one row of `news` (possibly multiple times), therefore the "total" group (consisting of all returned rows of the query without grouping) has only one distinct row of `news` and therefore all the requested values are constant per group. 
Just to have it said: this claim is indeed true. 
**But**: The DBMS just does not check this. I think this is because it does not expect a column of a query to be constant (if it is not obviously a constant, e.g. a literal).

This means, that the `WHERE` clause is not checked for enforcing the uniqueness of the queried columns per group. And thus PostgreSQL complains about your query.

So what you could do in this case: just `GROUP BY n.id` or `GROUP BY n.title, n.date`. I hope it is clear, why the second one works. The first approach works because PostgreSQL sees that you are grouping by the `PRIMARY KEY` (or more general: a `UNIQUE` constraint) of `n` and therefore recognizes that all the columns of `n` for all the rows in this group have only one value. 
This means that what you expected to be checked in the `WHERE` clause is only checked in the `GROUP BY` clause: the functional dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation, I really thought the uniqueness was handled to avoid adding what could be considered as a useless `GROUP BY` clause.